# how to modify multipart/form-data request body in Spring Cloud Gateway filter?

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-webflux, multipartform-data, spring-cloud-gateway

We are using spring cloud gateway to redirect request to relevant services. Right now we want to redirect upload request from legacy service to new microservice. So I need to change body content before redirect to new microservice. For example, renaming file part name as document.

```
POST /file HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8001
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------545040021353991257616713
Content-Length: 211 

----------------------------545040021353991257616713
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain 

Test

----------------------------545040021353991257616713--
```

After renaming `file` to `document` should look like below

```
POST /document HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8002
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------545040021353991257616713
Content-Length: 215 

----------------------------545040021353991257616713
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain 

Test 

----------------------------545040021353991257616713--
```

We created gateway filter [ModifyGatewayFilterFactory](https://github.com/arony/multipart-body-rewrite/blob/main/gateway/src/main/kotlin/com/gateway/ModifyGatewayFilterFactory.kt) in order to rewrite body.

Following part rewrites the body

```kotlin
 val modifiedRequest = serverRequest.bodyToMono(object : ParameterizedTypeReference<MultiValueMap<String, Part>>() {}).map {
            val request = LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Part>()
            request["document"] = it["file"]?.first() as Part
            request
 }
```

But the modified request weird as below

```
POST /document HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=Z2cuyWQnmuw5GIcYxKBr4L2lfJyqoRsxL
host: localhost:8002
transfer-encoding: chunked 

25
--Z2cuyWQnmuw5GIcYxKBr4L2lfJyqoRsxL 

83
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=gN215Av_pu7mDzk7v4cXymxXxqnRrrjpime 


27
--gN215Av_pu7mDzk7v4cXymxXxqnRrrjpime 

5e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain 


5
Test 

2

 
29
--gN215Av_pu7mDzk7v4cXymxXxqnRrrjpime-- 

2

 
27
--Z2cuyWQnmuw5GIcYxKBr4L2lfJyqoRsxL-- 

0
```

What did we do wrong?

The working example in this [Github](https://github.com/arony/multipart-body-rewrite) repo